# Can Cassandra be configured to use both internal and public IP addresses?

Tags: c#, cassandra, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to configure Cassandra on Google Compute Engine in such a way that the nodes of the cluster communicate directly with each other using the local network (with their internal IP-addresses), and that a client outside the cluster can talk to each node as well.

So far I've managed to create a cluster using DataStax OpsCenter using the internal IP-addresses, according to these instructions:
https://academy.datastax.com/demos/datastax-enterprise-deployment-guide-google-compute-engine
When I then connect using the DataStax C# driver with a connection string that contains all public IP-addresses and I retrieve the list of nodes, I get back a list with one public IP-address and the rest internal IP-addresses. This means that the driver will only be able to connect to one node.

My guess is that it's not possible and that it should be properly handled by the driver. But fixing the problem with a (simple) change to the Cassandra configuration would be preferred at this moment.

I'm using OpsCenter 5.2.1, Cassandra version 2.1.9.791.

Answer (score 3):

At Cassandra level you can set the [broadcast_address](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__broadcast_rpc_address).

At driver level you could create an [address translator policy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/2.7/html/T_Cassandra_IAddressTranslator.htm), but you would have to maintain a "private vs public ip" addresses dictionary.

Comment: Should I set it to the internal IP-address or to the public IP-address? It's currently not set, so it's set to the listen_address, which is the internal address. If I set it to the public IP-address, will the nodes still communicate with each other over the private network?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the link to the address translator policy! That will help me out until I figure out how to configure Cassandra properly.